# General Relativity as an equation of state?

Tags: metaphysics

So I prefer to interpret the theory of general relativity as an equation of state rather than an equation of mechanics.

There are others who prefer this [well](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/744914/thermodynamic-interpretation-of-the-cosmological-constant) (padmanabhan's work centers around this along more explicitly [here](https://youtu.be/Pcd911qSTBk)). What are the meta-physicists take of this? Quite often I struggle with vocabulary. I was hoping for a text which could help with this?

Comment: you may find SEP useful for research on this (maybe places like ncatlab also?) but in particular there is this nice article [Early Philosophical Interpretations of General Relativity](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/genrel-early/) that may be a good starting point

Comment: Whatever do you mean by "equation of state?" In particular, in contrast to an equation of mechanics. And what makes  you think that the theory of GR is *AN* equation, anyway? As to a text that could help with GR, try Gravitation. https://www.amazon.com/Gravitation-Charles-W-Misner/dp/0691177791/

Comment: This approach is one of active proposals for quantum gravity and is known as [entropic/emergent gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropic_gravity). Other than Padmanabhan, Jacobson and Verlinde worked on it, some recent tests undermine it. There is a philosophical discussion in [Linnemann-Visser's Hints towards the Emergent Nature of Gravity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.10503).